# Django session values occasionally not persisted

Tags: python, django, session

I have the following REST method that update the value of the session every time a jQuery tab is clicked to store the active tab.

```
@csrf_exempt
def update_active_tab_request(request):
    """
    Stores the active tab for a given tab item
    """
    for tab, active in request.GET.iteritems():
        request.session[tab] = int(active)

    return HttpResponse("OK", status=200)
```

It's a fairly simple routine, and the issue I'm having is that it that the value is not always stored in the session. I have viewed the web server logs, and I've sprinkled logging statements to verify that the code is being called. Everything appears to be working, but I've found that there is a chance that the session has not been updated when this method returns.

Thinking that it could be a performance/synchronization issue with updating the session, I've changed my session storage to `SESSION_ENGINE='django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'` .That didn't help. I've also set `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST=True` to always save the session. This too hasn't helped.

I'm at a loss to explain this behaviour. Any help in shedding light on the problem will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that the problem isn't that the session is expiring on you? By default `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` should be 2 weeks if you didn't modify it. Also, what storage are you using when not attempting to use `SESSION_ENGINE='django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'`

Comment: The session isn't expired, and I'm using the memcached backend. Switching to the default database session backend doesn't make a difference. The problem still persists.

Comment: Is the cache somehow filling up? If you use the cache for sessions, there is no guarantee that it will be persisted unless you use `cache_db`  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions

Comment: I do not think that it has to do with the cache filling up. The issue I'm facing occurs regardless of session engine. I only switched to the cache backend to test things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I've not been able to fix this, I've discovered a workaround. I manually store the active tab in the cache using Django's low level cache API.

```
from django.core.cache import cache


def save_viewer_tab(active, session_key, tab):
    cache.set(session_key + ":" + str(tab), int(active))


def get_viewer_tab(session_key, tab, default=0):
    return cache.get(session_key + ":" + str(tab), default)


@csrf_exempt
def update_active_tab_request(request):
    """
    Stores the active tab for a given tab item
    """
    session_key = request.session._session_key
    for tab, active in request.GET.iteritems():
        save_viewer_tab(active, session_key, tab)

    return HttpResponse("OK", status=200)
```

It works reliably, but I still do not understand why the previous code that stored the value of the tabs in the session was unreliable.

This is a stop gap measure until I find a proper solution.